# content_tag does return blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with content_tag into an helper, this piece of code

```
  def renderize(place_holder)
    content_tag(:div, "hello") do
      @raw_estimate.field_estimates.where(:field_position_id => FieldPosition.where(:place_holder => place_holder).first).each do |field|
        if field.field_type.alias == "input"
          content_tag :div do
            field.is_validate ? label_value = "*#{field.name}" : label_value = field.name
            content_tag(:label_tag, label_value) +
            text_field_tag("estimate[field_#{field.name.downcase.gsub(/\W+/, '')}]")
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

does not return anything, what am I missing?
Thank you

Comment: Do you call <%=  renderize(arg) %> ?

Comment: @apneadiving yes I did <%= renderize("user-data")%>. I tried also with   `def renderize(place_holder) content_tag(:div, "hello") end` and the output is rendered, I think it is something related at the .each block

Comment: don't use each for interacting array, use collect will will return an array of your rendered tags see http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag for the last few comments

Comment: What's the value of the horrible: @raw_estimate.field_estimates.where(:field_position_id => FieldPosition.where(:place_holder => place_holder).first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use each for interacting array, use collect will will return an array of your rendered tags see http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag for the last few comments

Answer (score 0):

This line is suspicious:

```
 :field_position_id => FieldPosition.where(:place_holder => place_holder).first
```

As far as I can understand, the left part is an id, while right part returns object FieldPosition, and not its id. That's why no objects are returned, and your helper has no content.

Comment: Nope, in Rails you can pass an object or object.id, it's the very same

Comment: you are right, i did not noticed this mistake but after fixed it i had the same behavior, chenged the .each into .collect and it works. thanks

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in another answer, using each won't work -- it doesn't return the internal contents of the block.  Just as an example, try running this in irb:

```
result = 1.upto(3) do |x| x; end
```

result will be "1"

Here's a cleaner test of your code, try it and see -- it won't return anything:

```
  def random_test
    content_tag(:div, "hello") do
      1.upto(3) do |x|
        content_tag(:p, x)
      end
    end
  end
```

Instead, you need to collect the output of your iterator, something along these lines:

```
  def random_test
    content_tag(:div, "hello") do
      1.upto(3) do |x|
        content_tag(:p, x)
      end
    end
  end
```